# Почему не добавляется текст полученный от пользователя в поля

Tags: javascript

код java script:

```
let lmenu_13=document.getElementsByClassName('name-value');
let lmenu_3=document.getElementsByClassName('budget-value');
open.addEventListener('click',()=> {
    money = prompt ("ваш бюджет?",'');
    while (isNaN(money) || money ===''|| money == null) {
         money = prompt ("ваш бюджет?",'');
    }
    lmenu_3.textContent=money; 
    lmenu_13.textContent = prompt("название вашего магазина?",'').toUpperCase();

});
```

html:

```
<div class="name-value"></div>
<div class="budget-value"></div>
```

получаю информацию в поля правильно а в  поля name-value и budget-value не добавляется.

Comment: метод `getElementsByClassName` - возвращает массив, даже если там 1 элемент. Выведите в консоль соответствующие пременные и увидете. Надеюсь, с понимаем того, что в таком случае делать - проблем не будет

Answer (score 1, accepted):

document.getElementsByClassName('budget-value')[0] - даст правильную ссылку. Согласен с комментатором выше. Можно пробелы еще добавить возле знака "=". Удачи)